# What is the cause of this toast message starting with 文件耗时?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, toast-notifications

Since this morning I have on my phone this weird toast message, that keep appearing.

[image: 文件耗时: 477 ms/number: 118]

> 文件耗时: 477 ms/number: 118

Does anyone have an idea what is this and how to remove it?

Comment: I managed to get those characters, and it seems "文件耗时" is a Chinese word for "Processed files".`

Comment: Related: [Toast message with Chinese characters, is it a virus?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/150523/toast-message-with-chinese-characters-is-it-a-virus)

Answer (score 1):

As I saw, it came from the app ES File manager

Comment: Provide more body on your answer. I still wouldn't understand why the app would bring this toast notification.

Comment: I dont understand neither, but since an update everyone who use this app have this toast message