# How do I remove what appears to be malware on my Nexus 5?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5, malware

I have a Nexus 5 phone running Android 6.0.1 (security patch level 1 Jun 2016).

It appears that over the past few days it has become infected with malware.

Periodically (every 10-15 minutes) a transparent notification appears near the bottom of the screen that looks like this (the numbers will change, and possibly the non-English text).

[image]

Here's what I have tried so far:

- Installed [Malwarebytes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.malwarebytes.antimalware&hl=en) and ran a scan but it couldn't detect it.
- Installed a few Antivirus programs ([AVG](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antivirus&hl=en), 360 Security) and it didn't find anything out of the ordinary.
- Installed [OS Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor&hl=en) to see if there are any suspicious processes running or network connections open but nothing stands out.
- Closed all running apps
- Rebooted the phone

The notifications keep popping up.  I'm a bit stuck here - this definitely looks like malware, but not sure where to go from here.  Obviously a factory reset is an option, but I'd like to expore other options first.

Any recommendations about how to proceed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toast message with Chinese characters, is it a virus?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/150523/toast-message-with-chinese-characters-is-it-a-virus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

After 2 days, uninstalling ES File Explorer seemed to do the trick - I'm not seeing these pop-ups anymore.

---

After further research this appears to be caused by an update to ES File Explorer (see [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/150523/toast-message-with-chinese-characters-is-it-a-virus)).  I have now uninstalled that app.

Comment: +1 for uninstall. If this is truly ES File Explorer-based, please update your answer after a few days to confirm. This would be strike 2 vs. ES File Explorer in a short time period, after their lock-screen advert incursion. Greater dispersion of this information is warranted in that case.